# How to remove first number from a number using regex as i want to implement in pentaho

Tags: regex, pentaho

I am getting a number as

```
1140302
```

I have to remove the first `1` from above number

```
140302
```

Comment: and you need a regex for that   ?????????????????????//

Comment: Use substring methods instead?

Comment: depends on the language that you are using ?

Comment: I would give -1 for this question but it's not even worth clicking this arrow.

Comment: the company you are setting an ETL up for is in big trouble ... :D

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a [wiki page](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Replace+in+String) about this:

```
regex = ^[0-9]([0-9]+)$

replace with = $1
```

Above regex matches length >= 2 numeric strings, and `$1` will contain the numbers without the first.

Comment: cant just use `^.` and replace with nothing

Comment: @aelor depends on the record set, `^.` would match `A123` which is highly unlikely to appear, but still using the character class or even `\d` is more specific.

Comment: ^. will match the first character irrespective of what you test

Comment: @aelor I know, but it would do that with everything, my solution also checks that we are working on the right kind of data. No point to argue.

Answer (score 0):

use `^.` and replace with `''`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/sW8fJ7